# date_i18n is not retrieving correct Month and Day in php/wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, datetime, internationalization

I have a html/php code as shown below:

**html/php code:**

```
<time datetime="<?php echo esc_attr(date_format($mn, 'H:i d-m-Y'))?>" data-timezone="<?php echo esc_attr($tz_param) ?>"><?php echo ucfirst(date_i18n('j F ', $mn->getTimeStamp() - (60 * 60 * 5))) . '<span>' . esc_attr(date_format($mn, 'H:i')) . '</span>'; ?>
</time>
```

The above html/php code prints the following on DOM:

```
<time datetime="05:00 13-05-2020" data-timezone="et">May 13 <span>05:00</span></time>

<time datetime="06:00 13-05-2020" data-timezone="et">May 13 <span>06:00</span></time>

<time datetime="11:00 13-05-2020" data-timezone="et">May 13 <span>11:00</span></time>

<time datetime="12:00 13-05-2020" data-timezone="et">May 13 <span>12:00</span></time>

<time datetime="00:00 14-05-2020" data-timezone="et">May 13 <span>00:00</span></time>   // Line A
```

At Line A, it's pulling May 13 instead of **May 14** and it happens only when time is 00:00 inside `datetime` attribute.

**Problem Statement:**

I am wondering what changes I should make in the **html/php** code above so that it pulls the correct Month and Day at Line A which is **May 14**.

I belive the issue is in this line `echo ucfirst(date_i18n('j F ', $mn->getTimeStamp() - (60 * 60 * 5)))`

Comment: Did you try wrapping it in strtotime. like this:  `echo ucfirst(date_i18n('j F ', strtotime($mn->getTimeStamp() - (60 * 60 * 5)))`

Comment: Nope, I will try now.

Comment: whoops I forgot a ")" at the end. here: `echo ucfirst(date_i18n('j F ', strtotime($mn->getTimeStamp() - (60 * 60 * 5))))` let me know if it worked.

Comment: hey, I tried now. It doesn't work. Let me know if you need more information. Its happening only when time is `00:00` inside `datetime` attribute.

Comment: Try putting the strtotime input in quotes. so like this: `echo ucfirst(date_i18n('j F ', strtotime("$mn->getTimeStamp() - (60 * 60 * 5))"))`